# A $\$5$ field bet in craps pays the bettor $\$10$ ($\$5$ in winnings, plus the $\$5$ bet back) when two dice total $2,3,4,9,10,11$, or $12$.

Tags: probability

a. What is the probability of winning a field bet? 
What is the expected change in assets from making this bet?

b. Some casinos pay double winnings if the dice total $2$ or $12$. How does this change answer is (a)

So I know the first part of (a) is $16/36$ but the others I am a little unsure about.

Answer (score 1):

The $\frac{16}{36}$ is right. So with probability $\frac{16}{36}$ the increase in assets is $5$, and with probability $\frac{20}{36}$ the "increase" in assets is $-5$.

So the expected increase in assets is
$$\frac{16}{36}(5)+\frac{20}{36}(-5).$$

The probability of $2$ or $12$ is $\frac{2}{36}$. When we play, three things can happen: (i) We get a double win (presumably $10$ bucks plus our money back). This has probability $\frac{2}{36}$; (ii) We get a single win. This has probability $\frac{14}{36}$; (ii) We lose, probability $\frac{20}{36}$.

So expected net change is
$$\frac{2}{36}(10)+\frac{14}{36}(5)+\frac{20}{36}(-5).$$

**Remark:** Notational overkill in this case, but for the first problem define random variable $X$ as our net win. Then $\Pr(X=5)=\frac{16}{36}$ and $\Pr(X=-5)=\frac{20}{36}$. We want to find $E(X)$.

Answer (score 0):

For a, as you say, you have a $\frac {16}{36}$ chance of winning $5$ and a $\frac {20}{36}$ chance of losing $5$.  So the expected value is $5 \cdot \frac {16}{36} - 5 \cdot \frac {20}{36}= - \frac {20}{36}=-\frac 59$.

For b) you now have three events.  You calculate the probability of each as you did in a, then sum up the probabilities times the gain/loss in each event.